# kill the app if it is not in foreground

Tags: android

Is there any way to kill the app as soon as it goes to background. For example, if I press the home key and again start the app, it goes to same activity but what I want is that as soon as app goes to background, it should be killed or it should start from the first activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Comment: How effective is that, if i get all the activities os my app's process and check if (runningAppProcessInfo.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) and if it return false, i do this : android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: As the above link states: you can NOT remove your app from the memory unless Android OS claims the resources. However, you can destroy the activities by using `finish` as the below answers suggest.

Comment: @Raghav: Do not use `killProcess()` in production code. Do not try to kill your own app. Android will terminate your process when appropriate.

Comment: but for security reasons, i have to logout the user as soon as the pp goes to background. How else can i do that.

Comment: @Raghav: Use time to determine whether or not the authentication credentials are out of date (e.g., time since logged in, time since last touched the app), not whether the app is "in the background". For example, in `onPause()`, update a `static long lastSeenTime` to be `System.currentTimeMillis()`. If, in `onResume()` of an activity, `lastSeenTime` is too old, `null` out your authentication credentials and redirect the user to your login activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare Many(but not all) devices allow the user to manipulate the system time which could potentially throw off any authentication checks that are based solely upon it.

Comment: @Tim: Then use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`, which is unaffected by end-user operations other than rebooting. That's probably a better answer here than `System.currentTimeMillis()` -- my apologies for not thinking of that when I wrote my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

it is not "killing" your app perse, but this will give you the effect you are after.

make the intents used to start your second-Nth activity with the FLAG_NO_HISTORY. That way they will be finished as soon as they leave the screen.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SomeOtherActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i);
```

When your activity leaves the screen it will be finished, which will cause it to launch from the starting activity the next time it gets launched from the home screen.

Comment: will it be efficient..I mean if no activity is kept as history, will it effect app

Comment: yes, it will effect the app in the exact way that you claim you want it to =).

Comment: what if i get all the activities of my app's process and check if (runningAppProcessInfo.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) and if it return false, i do this : android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: what will happen when i press back button. will it get me to previous screen if i use what u suggested above?

Answer (score -2):

You can catch the event when the user presses the home button as follows

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

You can also override the `onBackPressed()` method in your activity and call finish from there.

Comment: I don't think the system will let you listen for the home button in this way.

Comment: should i write it in all the activities?

Comment: The code snippet catches the home button's press event, the `onBackPressed()` method catches the press event of the back button.

Comment: @Raghav Note, that this will only finish the activity that you are currently in, not all your activities.

Comment: @paradx: "I assure you, this is working" -- I assure you, this does not work on Android 2.1 and higher. I just tested your code and, as expected, the `KEYCODE_HOME` event is not delivered. You are welcome to publish a complete sample project to demonstrate otherwise.

Comment: @paradx I just tested it, and it is not...The system prevents you from catching the Home button like this because it would be to easily exploitable by malware.

Comment: @CommonsWare fwiw I built for 1.6, it is not working at that API lvl either. Though my device is on a later version, perhaps that is why.

Comment: I havent tried this in the newer APIs, but on 1.6 devices and before it worked. I assumed it still works. My bad. Sorry for that.